# libgdx remove bullet from bullet array

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, sprite

im creating a 2d game. i have an array of a bullet class which i use to create my bullets. i also have another array this consisting sprites which move around the screen this being rendered every 3 to 4 seconds.

Problem:

when the bullet and other sprite meet at the same location the bullet should be removed or deleted and never comeback.

please help me...

code for rendering bullet:

bullet.java:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Bullet{

public Vector2 bulletLocation = new Vector2(0, 0);
public Vector2 bulletVelocity = new Vector2(0, 0);

public Bullet(Vector2 sentLocation, Vector2 sentVelocity) {
    bulletLocation = new Vector2(sentLocation.x, sentLocation.y);
    bulletVelocity = new Vector2(sentVelocity.x, sentVelocity.y);
}

public void Update() {
    bulletLocation.x += bulletVelocity.x;
    bulletLocation.y += bulletVelocity.y;
}
}
```

main class:

```
ArrayList<Bullet> bulletManager = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
Array<Other> OthersManager = new Array<Other>();
Bullet currentbullet;
Other currentOthers;
```

render();

```
int other = 0;
while (other < OthersManager.size) {
currentOthers = OthersManager.get(other);
        if (currentOthers.OtherLocation.x > guy.getX()) {
            currentOthers.OtherVelocity.x = -2f;
        }
        if (currentOthers.OtherLocation.x < guy.getX()) {
            currentOthers.OtherVelocity.x = 2f;
        }
        currentOthers.Update();
        others.setPosition(currentOthers.OtherLocation.x,currentOthers.OtherLocation.y);
        others.draw(batch);
        other++;
    }

    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < bulletManager.size()) {
        currentbullet = bulletManager.get(counter);
        currentbullet.Update();
        shoot.setPosition(currentbullet.bulletLocation.x,currentbullet.bulletLocation.y);
        if(currentOthers.OtherLocation.x == currentbullet.bulletLocation.x){
            bulletManager.remove(currentbullet);
        }
        shoot.draw(batch);
        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: Have you written any code for collision?

Comment: yeah. sorry i didnt show it. check my code again I've added it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is in this block of code:

```
    if(currentOthers.OtherLocation.x == currentbullet.bulletLocation.x){
        bulletManager.remove(currentbullet);
    }
```

I would suggest you to use epsilonEquals method from Vector2 class to check whether your currentOthers.OtherLocation matches currentbullet.bulletLocation:

```
    if(currentOthers.OtherLocation.epsilonEquals(currentbullet.bulletLocation)){
        bulletManager.remove(currentbullet);
    }
```

Moreover you can use epsilonEquals with float epsilon:
[documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#epsilonEquals-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2-float-)